# Angularjs-UI sortable multiple div list

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I am trying to get sortable to work.

```
 <ul ui-sortable='data.sortableOptions' ng-model="dp.claims" class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="c in dp.claims">
            <div> {{c.field1}} </div>
            <div> {{c.field2}} </div>
            <div> {{c.field3}} </div>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

I can't seem to grab and drag anything.  The important part of this question is the 3 div's in the li

I admit, I don't understand what this line in the docs means: "ui-sortable element should only contain one ng-repeat and not any other elements (above or below)."

And I am able to get it to work with a table.

Any insights?

Comment: http://codepen.io/thgreasi/pen/KtsFH

Comment: Not sure what you are telling me.  I know I can get <ul ui-sortable='data.sortableOptions' ng-model="dp.claims" class="list-unstyled"><li ng-repeat="c in dp.claims">{{c.field1}}</li></ul> to work.

Comment: That's full working example you can compare your code

Comment: Thanks, but not an example that addresses the question

Comment: Do you want to sort between `<div> {{c.field1}} </div>
            <div> {{c.field2}} </div>
            <div> {{c.field3}} </div>`  ??   Please create a fiddle of your code !

Comment: I want to drag the 'row' of three fields and drop above or below another row of three fields

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the docs do say "ui-sortable element should only contain one ng-repeat and not any other elements (above or below)." which makes it hard to have 3 divs in the li.  However, there is a solution.

You can use tg-dynamic-directive (at https://github.com/thgreasi/tg-dynamic-directive) to solve this.  Don't forget to include it, and put 'tg.dynamicDirective' in your dependencies.  Basically you take out the middle part in between the li tags, in this case the 3 divs, and you put it in another file and link to it.

```
 <ul ui-sortable='data.sortableOptions' ng-model="dp.claims" class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="c in dp.claims">

        </li>
 </ul>
```

Then in another file put the innards, like innards.html:

```
        <div> {{c.field1}} </div>
        <div> {{c.field2}} </div>
        <div> {{c.field3}} </div>
```

And replace the innards with:

```
<ul ui-sortable='data.sortableOptions' ng-model="dp.claims" class="list-unstyled">
        <li ng-repeat="c in dp.claims">
           <tg-dynamic-directive ng-model="c" tg-dynamic-directive-view="getView">
           </tg-dynamic-directive>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

And in your controller put something like:

```
 $scope.getView = function(item) {
  if item {
    return 'innards.html';
  return null;
 };
```

Anyways the docs go over it pretty well.  I realize this question is pretty old but I just ran into this myself and got it working so hopefully it helps someone else.